# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'

Tags: c#, linq, generics, hashtable, radtreeview

I'm getting the below error when trying to create a Key,Value pair and load it into a HashTable

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>'` to 'System.Collections.Hashtable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Below is the code snippet

```
hashtable selectedValues = radTree.CheckedNodes.Where(node => node.Level == 0).Select(row => new
        {
            key = row.Value,
            Value = row.Text
        });
```

In the above query I'm trying to get the Key and Value of selected checkboxes (for a particular level) in a Telerik RadTreeControl and load them into a hashtable.

Is there a way in LINQ that we could cast the result to hashtable or is it better that I just go with Dictionary since we have the `ToDictionary()` method available ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to Hashtable? ToDictionary is already implemented and you can use it easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to just use a Dictionary.

Otherwise you can use [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277(v=vs.100).aspx) and then pass that to the [constructor of a hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdkta2sx.aspx) if you really want.